# Permitir consultas apenas de numeros no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber se tem como impedir que seja consultado palavras, caracteres e outras coisas que possam fazer um sql injection em um site. estou desenvolvendo um sistema pra histórico de um site, segue o script:

se possível também gostaria de saber como dar um else no while, pq ta retornando erro.

```
$id = $_COOKIE["id"];
$novoId = "$cont[id]";

if (!preg_match("/\b{$novoId}\b/", $id)) {
    setcookie("id", $id .= "{$novoId},");
}
$historico = rtrim($id, ',') . '';

$beta = mysql_query("SELECT aid FROM `lista` WHERE aid IN($historico)");
while (list($aid) = mysql_fetch_array($beta)) {
$devolver .= ' '.$aid.'  ';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível sim. Basta você verificar se é um inteiro ou valor número e caso não seja, exibir uma mensagem de erro.

**Usando preg_match:**

```
<?php

/* Verifica se a variável contém somente números */
if (preg_match("/^\d+$/", $id)) {
    /* Faz a busca */
}
```

**Usando is_numeric:**

```
<?php

/* Verifica se a variável contém um valor número, independente da variável ser do tipo "int" ou "string" */
if (is_numeric($id)) {
    /* Faz a busca */
}
```

**Usando is_int ou is_integer:**

```
<?php

/* Verifica se a variável é do tipo "inteiro" */
if (is_int($id)) {
    /* Faz a busca */
}
```

Você também pode converter para inteiro.

```
<?php

$id = "4165";

var_dump( (int)"4165" );       // 4165
var_dump( (int)4165.7 );       // 4165
var_dump( (int)false );        // 0
var_dump( (int)true );         // 1
var_dump( (int)"valdeir" );    // 0

echo PHP_EOL;
echo "----------";
echo PHP_EOL;

var_dump( intval("4165") );     // 4165
var_dump( intval(4165.7) );     // 4165
var_dump( intval(false) );      // 0
var_dump( intval(true) );       // 1
var_dump( intval("valdeir") );  // 0
```

Se você tiver usando múltiplos *ID's*, você pode utilizar a função `array_map`. Ex:

```
<?php

$ids = ["4165", 4165.7, false, true, "valdeir"];

$newIds = array_map(function($value) {
    return (int)$value;
}, $ids);


var_dump($newIds);
```

Você também pode filtrar apenas os valores números.

```
<?php

$ids = "4165,4165.7,false,true,valdeir,12";
$ids = explode(",", $ids);

$newIds = array_filter($ids, function($value) {
    /* Retorna apenas os números inteiros */
    return is_numeric($value);
});


var_dump( implode(",", $newIds) );

// Output: 4165,4165,12
```

Comment: Cada ID e separado por virgula, ainda assim funcionará?

Comment: @Gabriel utilizando a função `array_map` funciona sim. Adicionei uma nova função para filtrar apenas os valores números. Basta utilizar o `explode` para transformar em `array` e depois o `implode` para juntar apenas os novos valores.

Comment: usar o $ids = explode(",", $ids); e (  implode(",", $newIds)) vai remover a ultima virgula, "se houver", porque o id captura com"," na frente, as vezes fica algo tipo ids="1,2,3,4,"

Comment: @Gabriel se houver uma vírgula no final da string, o explode irá retornar um valor vazio e o array_filter irá eliminar esse valor. Dessa forma "1,2,3,4," ficará "1,2,3,4"

Comment: Demonstração: https://ideone.com/EELeIc